# How to fix Uncaught Error: Cannot use e "__Schema" from another module or realm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, graphql

I have a Rails application with GraphQL API which works fine when running in development. After I deployed the app to Heroku, visiting the GraphiQL interface at `/graphiql` I get this error below:

```
Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
    at n.default (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:597)
    at u (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at o (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at M (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at R (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at new P (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at P (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807)
    at Object.129.../jsutils/isInvalid (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:815)
    at i (application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12)
    at application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
n.default @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:597
u @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
o @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
M @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
R @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
P @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
P @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:807
129.../jsutils/isInvalid @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:815
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
132.../error/GraphQLError @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:831
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
96../execution/execute @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:588
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
97../error @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:588
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:84
12.../utility/CodeMirrorSizer @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:84
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
22../components/GraphiQL @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:139
i @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
t @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
(anonymous) @ application-d621ca4100ba6f2e72e972ecd2a7ddcd5d2ec26b6f1fcf2932d68e2e12c78794.js:12
```

Meanwhile, here's my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: '/graphiql', graphql_path: '/graphql'
  get 'home/index'
  post '/graphql', to: 'graphql#execute'
  root 'home#index'
end
```

And I am using these versions of `graphql` and `graphiql-rails` respectively:

```
graphql (1.10.8)
graphiql-rails (1.7.0)
```

Comment: hello, have you fixed the problem?

Comment: I actually improvised. Although it wasn't the best fix, I had to due to the strict deadline I had for the project. I build a GraphiQL interface using nodeJs and then configured Rails to mount the NodeJs GraphiQL interface on production (Heroku).